# Mapreduce logs - File vs HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I submitted a mapreduce and this is my output.

What is the difference between the FILE and HDFS as given below?

```
16/01/07 21:49:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 38
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=4011012
        FILE: Number of bytes written=8400605
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=11928267
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=883509
        HDFS: Number of read operations=37
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FILE - gives the amount of I/O performed on intermediate files, which are maintained internally between map and reduce phase (sort & shuffle phase)

HDFS - Amount of data read by mapper and data written by reducer.